# ionic/cordova htm2pdf and save in device location

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

Image bigger then pdf page needs to get split to another image & added to next page

I am using html2canvas and jsPDF for Pdf creation.

I want a solution on below :

I have a table rows which can increase depends upon the records I get from database.
The Rows could be more then the size of the Pdf page.
I want to display that single canvas image in two different pages. (1st image in page 1 as it will get fit properly; but for 2nd the remaining image need to add it to second page)
I dont want to compromise on quality of Image & no compression